# Rails 5 : content_for :javascript do is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I have shopify app and I wanted to initialise shopify bar in my app

I Used shopify gem for rails and Initialise using

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
      ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({

        title: "Home",
        icon: "<%= asset_path('favicon.ico') %>"
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

But this is not working and I can not see bar in shopify app , I found out that , in my app content for java script is not working because it's not loading any java script

Comment: I have no idea how shopify works, but are you actually yielding your javascript anywhere?

Comment: where are you trying to load it ?

Comment: I have used this both : https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app and https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app , This will load Shopify SDK